# Tomcat NIO - Actual Usage

Tags: apache, tomcat, nio

We have been using Tomcat and axis2 for SOAP service in production.

But, during some high traffic condition, we find CPU constantly high.

We found that the netstat during that time, we had lot of connections from external clients.

We think CPU high might be due to high context switching between these threads since these threads are blocking in nature.

So, we thought we can enable NIO in our tomcat connectors. We thought this can reduce the no of threads to process many connections.

But, when we run enabled NIO and ran traffic, we found from thread stack dump that there were same amount of threads in apache tomcat and CPU still high.

The only difference was the name of thread in dump (NIO - http-exec).

What is wrong in this configuration?

server.xml

```
<Connector port="8182" 
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" 
connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Since, maxThreads still exist, that many threads are getting created to handle high traffic in NIO as well as BIO.

I thought enabling NIO would reduce threads handling HTTP Requests from clients.

Should I do changes in my HTTPServlet code to actually use NIO to the fullest.

Thanks and Regards,
Sashi

Comment: As you haven't posted your configuration, it is impossible for anyone to tell you what's wrong with, if anything. But you're almost certainly barking up the wrong tree. High CPU usage will be from your application, not thread context-switching. Off topic too.

Comment: Why do you think that thread context switching might not cause high CPU Usage? I am posting my server.xml now.

Comment: It is for you to tell us why you think it does, compared with all the work your application has to do. It's your hypothesis, and it isn't plausible.

Comment: Ok I agree. But, I would like to see and understand the difference between NIO and BIO connectors of Tomcat. But, since actual work is performed (HTTP Request and Response) is handled by worker thread configured as  maxThreads, I dont see any major difference between the connectors.

Comment: That's what I said. You're looking in the wrong place. What you should be doing is profiling your application, instead of guessing games.